# Simulate closing/reopening the browser in cucumber/capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, capybara

I'm writing cucumber tests to test user 'Remember me' type functionality, and in order to do that in real life the user would close their browser, reopen their browser, and come back to the site.

My test so far looks like this:

```
Scenario: 'Remember me' checked
  Given I have checked "Remember me"
  And I am logged in as "test@test.com"
  When I close and re-open my browser
  And I come back to the dashboard
  Then I should be on the dashboard
```

However I don't know what to fill in for the 'When I close and re-open the browser' step definition.

Does anyone know how I would do this (or if this isn't what I should be doing, how I should be testing it?)

Comment: Did you find answer for you question? we are trying to test localStorage usage and our offline application. sometimes we need to reopen browser or open in another browser(it could be the same browser but with clean localstorage data and empty cookies). we have already created fork of another fork(html5 support) and merged with capybara-webkit(0.7.2) with localStorage support. But now we have troubles with reopen browser steps.

Comment: Did you find answer to your question?

Comment: I didn't find an answer, but ultimately ended up discarding the test. Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

I use [Show me the cookies](https://github.com/nruth/show_me_the_cookies).

Add to bundle with `gem 'show_me_the_cookies'` and then add `World(ShowMeTheCookies)` in your `features/support/env.rb`

Then just define a step:

```
When /^I reopen the browser$/ do
  expire_cookies
  visit [ current_path, page.driver.request.env['QUERY_STRING'] ].reject(&:blank?).join('?')
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps create a second Capybara session? http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Session

Answer (score 1):

You can just clear the cookies.

```
When /^I clear cookies$/ do
  browser = Capybara.current_session.driver.browser
  browser.manage.delete_all_cookies
end
```

Comment: I think the scenarios is support to verifying the the cookie is set and read correctly across different sessions, so clearing the cookies would break the test.

Answer (score 1):

This gem makes it easy: https://github.com/nruth/show_me_the_cookies

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to test the same thing, got it work like this:

```
When(/^I close and reopen the browser$/) do
  # Get cookies we want to keep
  remember_me_cookie = page.driver.browser.manage.cookie_named('remember_user_token')

  # Close the window and delete the cookies
  page.driver.quit

  # Reopen the window
  page.driver.switch_to_window(page.driver.current_window_handle)

  # Go to our domain and add our cookies back in
  visit('/') 
  remember_me_cookie.nil? ? @current_user = nil : page.driver.browser.manage.add_cookie(remember_me_cookie) 

  # Refresh the domain to activate the cookies
  visit('/') 
end
```

A few things:

- `page.driver.quit` removes the cookies, thats why I am doing the dance with the cookies
- I tried closing the window using `page.driver.close_window(page.driver.current_window_handle)`, then switching back to it with `page.driver.switch_to_window(handle)` but that didn't work
- I tried closing the window using `page.driver.close_window(page.driver.current_window_handle)`, then switching to a new window `page.driver.switch_to_window(page.driver.open_new_window)` but that didn't work

I feel like I am not really understanding how the `browser` / `window` relationship is working in Capybara. Also it seems like copying over the cookies is kind of cheating my integration test. Hopefully there is a better way to achieve all of this in future versions.